# Getting diamond altcodes when trying to use curl

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to get the contents of this page: https://www.realestate.com.au/nsw/karuah-2324/

However, when I use the below code to get the page contents, I get this result:

```
�]R�r�@����wSlg��-�RSƼt���l��鿷I��鋤#�t�H2n����p�ٳ"����Y�� ��A�uF�u�JT��n��q��_�Ϡ_V'��Wi��:���[|c�w�%�iVbt��^�>:��������d��U��.�������{C��H�H��zk��<�E�8 ����p"�ST�H$$��D�Bi��i�,i��R�9]1H��1������>�����9�`��Z�'��ӽ���i�~�6�)h#��g��ԟ�t������^W���捠�H8Q�]�`�x��`0�>�|J&���DEGPms�>-z�U[h��ˠh/W�<��N�� �7�H(:rYa���-X{R\��� Go�|\DK���O�g�+�`��}g'{�����<�����#�8�6�
```

My code:

```
<?php
function visit_url_with_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    // Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Ignore SSL certificate verification (use in a safe environment)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // Ignore SSL certificate verification (use in a safe environment)

    // Execute cURL and store the response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for cURL errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    // Close cURL session
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$url = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/nsw/karuah-2324/';
$html = visit_url_with_curl($url);

// Print the HTML content of the page
echo $html;
?>
```

What can I do to get the contents properly? If you visit the site, you will see the HTML is cleaner and has a lot of info in it.

Comment: The HTTP response is improperly-formatted and Curl returns it still gzipped, but your browser "helpfully" fixes broken responses like this. But even if you _do_ decode it it's just an interstitial JavaScript snippet that sends you on a runaround. This is all intended to befuddle scrapers. If you want access to the data you need to contact the site operator.

Answer (score 0):

Is the content you get gzip compressed?
You need to add an extra setting to cURL to properly read the coded content from the website.

Try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');  // Accepts all encodings and allows cURL to decode them automatically
```

Comment: That now shows me something in readable text, but it is still not the html text

Comment: That readable text, what is it?

Comment: If you visit https://www.realestate.com.au/nsw/karuah-2324/ and go to the page source, there are lots of info in there. However, this code just shows ` 
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script>window.KPSDK={};KPSDK.now=typeof performance!=='undefined'&&performance.now?performance.now.bind(performance):Date.now.bind(Date);KPSDK.start=KPSDK.now();</script><script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/ips.js"></script></body></html>`